# How to stop Excel at different locales from renaming worksheet functions

Tags: excel, localization, excel-formula, vba

Here is the situation. I have an Excel worksheet that I developed in the US that uses some VBA code in addition to the worksheet function `CONVERT()` (available with analysis addin, to convert units). I send the worksheet to Germany to be filled up, and when I get it back, it has renamed my convert functions to `UMWANDELN()` which breaks my sheet in the US.

My question is if I write a VBA wrapper to `WorksheetFunction.Convert()` and use that instead of the cell formula `=CONVERT()`, will the German office break it, because convert will not be available. Will `WorksheetFunction.Umwandeln()` be available? To I try both with error catching?

So how can I make my Worksheet usable both in the US and in Germany if I need to rely on the `CONVERT()` function? Is there is VBA solution, or am I stuck?

Another workaround would be to re-write my own convert unit function which might be a hassle with all the different combinations I have.

Comment: is this the only function that gets translated? I am thinking iterate over cells and replace UMWANDELN() with CONVERT() once you get the spreadsheet back. May not be the best approach but the first one that comes to my head at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current workaround (not the best) is to replace all calls to `=CONVERT()` with calls to

```
Public Function ConvertUnit(ByVal value As Double, ByVal from_unit As String, ByVal to_unit As String) As Variant
    ConvertUnit = WorksheetFunction.Convert(value, from_unit, to_unit)
End Function
```

and it seems to survive the round trip from US to Germany. I am hoping the community is going to shed some more insight into the situation and propose so novel solutions.